# Javascript String Array Access Returns Chars

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, string

Okay, so I have an array of strings on a webpage in Javascript, defined like so:

```
var arr = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear"]; //this is populated by a php script prior to being sent to the client.
```

The problem is, when I attempt to access these items in a for loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    alert(arr[i]);
}
```

My output would be:

```
A
p
p
```

So, the array seems to be accessed one character at a time, which is of course not the reason I created the array.

I really cannot fathom why this would happen. Can anyone see a problem?

EDIT: The full code - it's not very nice but it's a work in progress:

```
var votes = {<?php foreach ($options as $o) { echo ' "'.$o['name'].'":"'.$o['votes'].'"'; if (next($options)) { echo ','; } } ?>};
var name = [<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($options); $i++) { echo ' "'.$options[$i]['name'].'"'; if ($i < count($options)-1) { echo ','; } } ?> ];

function run(num) {
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = '';


for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById(i+1).checked)
    {
        votes[name[i]] = (parseInt(votes[name[i]]) + 1);
        document.getElementById(num+(i+1)).checked = true;
    }
    if (document.getElementById(num+(i+1)).checked)
    {
        votes[name[i]] = (parseInt(votes[name[i]]) + 1);
    }

    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += name[i] + ': ' + votes[name[i]] + '<br />';
    console.log('arr: ', name, 'j: ', name.length);
}

$.ajax("vote.php", {
        data:votes,
            });
}
```

Here is Options

```
"options" : [
    {
        "name"  : "Children of Men",
        "id"    : "1",
        "votes" : "0"
    },
    {
        "name"  : "City of God",
        "id"    : "2",
        "votes" : "0"
    },
    {
        "name"  : "Hidden",
        "id"    : "3",
        "votes" : "0"
    },
    {
        "name"  : "We Need To Talk About Kevin",
        "id"    : "4",
        "votes" : "0"
    }
]
```

Comment: That code won't do what you say it's doing, so something must be wrong with the way you're getting the array from your server to the browser.

Comment: It sounds like you reassigned `arr` to be one element of the original `arr` array.

Comment: What will be shown if you do `alert(arr);` ?

Comment: Works here -- http://jsfiddle.net/DFpW3/

Comment: alert(arr) would show "Apple,Orange,Pear" (without quotes)

Comment: @Luke: And what is `alert(typeof arr)`? Sounds like it was a string somehow

Comment: @Bergi it says string. But how could this be?

Comment: Since it looks like the php that is the culprit, I have included it in the OP.

Comment: @Luke: Not with the above code. Could you please show us your actual code in whole (thanks for the PHP part), what ends up in the source of the page?

Comment: +1 please show us the actual output being sent to the browser.

Comment: The source of the page is exactly what I expect. var name = [ "Children of Men", "City of God", "Hidden", "We Need To Talk About Kevin" ];

Comment: Options just comes straight out of a json file. I have added it to the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I "fixed" this problem by defining the Array with

```
new Array( 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear' );
```

I could not figure out the actual issue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear'],
    i,
    j = arr.length;

console.log('Array?: ', arr.toString() == '[object Array]'); // edited

for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    console.log('arr: ', arr, 'j: ', j);
}
```

Above console.log should show you what is wrong.

Comment: in my console.log arr is the contents of the array separated by commas, and j is 62... Which is the number of characters in the 'arr' output.

Really cannot figure out why it is doing that.

Comment: @Luke OK, what about `toString.call(arr) == '[object Array]';` is it true?

Comment: @Luke OK, so you have a string not an array. The problem is in your php code which makes not an array but a string.

Comment: @Luke Somehow you have structure like this: `'Apple,Orange,Pear'` but you need it to be like this: `['Apple','Orange','Pear']`